# How to get p5.js working in WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

**Context:**

I'm trying to get p5.js library working on a Wordpress installation build with Sage starter theme.

All files seems to be in their place:

p5.min.js is in `dist` folder.

p5.min.js is correctly enqueued at the end of the `body`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//localhost:3000/app/themes/tlm/dist/scripts/p5.min.js"></script>
```

**Problem:**

When I try to create an instance of p5, I get `'p5' is not defined` eslint error.

```
var sketch = function(p) {
  p.setup = function () {
    p.createCanvas(500, 500);
    p.background(200);
  };
};
new p5(sketch);
```

I have a low level of JS. Why p5 is undefined? How can I debug it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the p5 variable as a global.

**How?**

Just add this line at the top of your JavaScript  file

/* global p5 */